# How to display/read results (ops/sec)?

Tags: javascript, benchmark.js

I am able to successfully create and run benchmark suite, but not sure how to get the benchmark values of each output, `this.filter('fastest').pluck('name')` in `onComplete` gives me the name of the fastest operation, but I want the `ops/sec` value of each function in the test suite. how to get that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `onComplete` callback you can access your benchmarks through `this` keyword (which will reference to the current [BenchmarkSuite](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#Suite) object) like this:

```
var bench1 = this[0];
var bench2 = this[1];
...
var benchN = this[N-1];
```

Each `bench` is instance of [Benchmark](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#Benchmark). So you can get any information you want (see [Benchmark.prototype](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_aborted) ). To get `ops/sec` value use [`.hz`](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_hz) property of benchmark. A small example for better understanding:

```
new Benchmark.Suite()
.add('test1', function() {
    // some code
})
.add('test2', function() {
    // some code
})
.on('complete', function() {
    var benchTest1 = this[0]; // gets benchmark for test1
    var benchTest2 = this[1]; // gets benchmark for test2

    console.log(benchTest1.hz); // ops/sec
    // benchmark info in format: 
    // test2 x 1,706,681 ops/sec ±1.18% (92 runs sampled)
    console.log(benchTest2.toString()); 

    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
})
.run();
```